# Ionic Scroll to a negative position

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have an ion scroll that scrolls accourding other component. To do that i use the function `scroll1.scrollTo(left, top, false);`

However, this function doesn't allow to scroll to a negative position like

`scroll1.scrollTo(left, -50, false);`

So is it possible to achieve this ?

My scroll must do scrolling without any user interaction (this is why i use the scrollTo function), and my main goal with the negative top position is to simulate a bouncing effect.

Answer (score 0):

This is clearly possible with [VelocityJS](http://julian.com/research/velocity/)
Velocity is a very powerfull FULL Javascript animation / scroll and much more librairy.

Demo of velocity Scroll : [demo scroll velocity](http://codepen.io/julianshapiro/pen/kBuEi)

```js
$element
    /* Then scroll to a position 250 pixels BELOW the div. */
    .velocity("scroll", { duration: 750, offset: 250 })
    /* Scroll to a position 50 pixels ABOVE the div. */
    .velocity("scroll", { duration: 750, offset: -50 });
```

Comment: Does velocity allow drag effects ? Like ionic

Comment: Velocity is for animation. if you want to link velocity with drag effect, look at $ionicScrollDelegate